# Random tree procedure in ANSI-C - what generates SIGSEGV?

Tags: pointers, data-structures, ansi-c

In main.c the tree is declared and initiated, but procedure:

```
void MakeTree(Tree T, int n)
{
    int i, r;
    Node *x, *p;
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        Node * new = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        new->key = rand() % 100;
        x = T.root;
        NodeInit(p);
        while(x != NULL)
        {
            p = x;
            r = rand() % 2;
            if(r == 0) x = p->left;
            else x = p->right;
        }
        new->parent = p;

        if (T.root == NULL) 
            T.root = new;
        else
            if (r == 0)
            {
                p->left = new;
            }
            else 
            {
                p->right = new;
            }
    }
}
```

generates memory violation error in WHILE loop in line below:

else x = p->right;

What have I missed in this assignment?

Comment: Using `new` as a variable name is just a mean thing to do to us poor C++ programmers.

Comment: @Bathsheba but it's ANSI C, so he's well within his rights, and it's not an unusual thing to do.

Comment: There is a glaring error in your final `if()` statement, but I urge you to find it yourself. I also urge you to step through your program in a debugger, to find the problems yourself.  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Also, you will save yourself a lot of trouble if you ALWAYS put `{ }` and corresponding newlines around blocks belonging to `if` statements etc.

Comment: @slim - aww, I saw it - edited. I used debugger before posting and found that this part generates SIGSEGV: x = p->left; (or x = p->right; due to r random variable). I can't understand what's wrong with this pointer.

Comment: Using a debugger is more than just finding what line a fault occurs. Set a breakpoint. Step through line by line. Look at the variables' contents as you go, and compare with what you expect to happen.